# Work done on gas problem with movable set

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, work, gas

I found two different version of an exercise where the work is considered in a different way. Consider a gas in a tank divided in two parts by a **movable** set. The set in $B$ is also movable. If a constant force is applied to the set in $B$, what is the work done by the gas?
[image]

Indipendently from the trasofrmation of the gas, since $f$ is constant one can say that $\mathscr{W}=\frac{f}{S} \Delta V$. The problem is: what is $\Delta V$?

In the first version I found $\Delta V$ set equal to $\Delta V_B$, while in the other $\Delta V= \Delta V_A + \Delta V_B$.

I think the second one is the correct one, but I wanted to be sure. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what work you refer to. If it is the work made by gas B on the piston at the right, then this work is $-P\Delta V$ because the length the piston moves is given by the change in the total volume (regardless of the motion of the other piston). This will be also the net work done on the system A+B.

To compute the net work by gas B you need to add the positive work done by gas B on gas A, which will be $P\Delta V_A$, thus $W_B^{total}=P\Delta V_A-P\Delta V=- P\Delta V_B $.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your answer by figure below:
[image]

$$\Delta V_B=S(x_{B,2}-x_{B,1})-S(x_{A,2}-x_{A,1})= \Delta V-\Delta V_A$$

Answer (score 0):

The second one is correct. Work is defined by $$w=F \cdot dx$$ where x is travel distance, which can be calculated by $$dx \cdot S = dV$$ Here you can see dV is not $dV_B$. It should be total volume change.